# How to group sencha touch 2 radio fields

Tags: radio-button, touch, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

This is my sencha touch 2 code:

```
Ext.define("10.view.Main", {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    requires: ['Ext.form.FieldSet'],

    config: {
        title: 'Main',
        scrollable: 'both',
        editable: false,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                name: 'color',
                value: 'red',
                label: 'Red',
                checked: true
            },

            {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                name: 'color',
                value: 'blue',
                label: 'Blue'
            }]
        }]
    }
});
```

Here is the preview of the code. What I get is this:

[image: what i get is this]

I want to group my radio fields like given below.

[image: what i need is this]

How can I do it?

Comment: Is there any plugin or something to do so?

Answer (score 0):

At the following link you can find an example. Hope it works for you.
http://sureshdotariya.blogspot.be/2013/05/how-to-group-radio-buttons-in-form.html

Greets